# Convert .xsd file to WSDL

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I have a `.xsd` file and need to convert it to WSDL. How can I do that? Is converting it even the right approach? The `.xsd` file contains both request and response data.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do that so easily. Usually, the `xsd` defines the structure (type) of the input and output messages. The `wsdl` used the xsd to define the operations that will be exposed by the service. An `operation` has usually a name and a pair of input and output messages.

I don't see how a tool could "reconstruct" the operations out of only the xsd only, except if it uses naming convention. E.g. messages `requestDoIt` and `responseDoIt` --> operation `DoIt`. If the xsd already contains the operations (which would be unusual) that could be ok, but it doesn't seem to be your case.

Manually creating the wsdl shouldn't be too long.

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="..." targetNamespace="...">
        <xsd:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="MySchema.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
...
 <wsdl:portType name="...">
    <wsdl:operation name="doIt">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:requestDoIt"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:responseDoIt"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

Have a look at [WSDL essentials](http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/1602051/WSDL-Essentials.htm) to get the general structure of the wsdl.

Or you can give a try to the tool [WSDL Generator](http://www.theprogrammerfactory.com/) (from http://www.theprogrammerfactory.com/) whose purpose is apparently to ease this task. (Note that I never used it).

Another approach would be to generate classes out of the xsd, then use them to define the service class manually (this is the tedious part of matching types together into the corresponding operation) and then use another tool to transform the service class back into a complete wsdl. There are various tools available to convert to/from xsd and wsdl, for both Java or C#: wsgen, wsimport, xsd.exe, wsdl.exe.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920086/generating-a-wsdl-from-a-xsd-file

Comment: Tried using the WSDL Generator from  http://www.theprogrammerfactory.com/ and it didn't create a WSDL that conformed to the provided XSD. For example it is not able to properly create a message element as it ignores any input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Services Description Language Tool (Wsdl.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: is it downlaodable file? i am not getting the .exe in it ?

Comment: you will find it in the sdk folder

Answer (score 0):

I realized in C# "XMas XSD Schema Tool" to incorporate an XSD Schema structure into a WSDL file.
The WSDL file produced includes minimal structures to be used in a web service consumer tool.
If you want to try it for free, you have the manual and download link here: https://www.nick4name.eu/downloads/xmas_en/
Let me know your opinion.