# What tool can I use to merge wsdl and xsd file?

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl

I have two files, one with webservice description (wsdl), second with data structures used in webservice (xsd). I have nothing more, webservice doesn't work yet. I need to merge them into one, because Delphi 7 WSDL Importer doesn't handle included xsd files to well. Where can I find tool to do it?

**EDIT**

I copied xsd content into `<types>` section and it works. I tried it before, but I must have made a mistake and Delphi WSDL import didn't work. I have to improve my copy/paste skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied xsd content into  section and it works. I tried it before, but I must have made a mistake and Delphi WSDL import didn't work. I have to improve my copy/paste skills.

Answer (score 6):

You might change the `include` into an `import`.
I have seen various tools handling either one better than the other.

As an alternative, use [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/download.html): here you can edit your WSDL and import your XSD into it.

[This question has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920086/generating-a-wsdl-from-a-xsd-file) on how to place the content of the XSD into the WSDL.

Comment: Thanks but there is already `<xsd:import namespace="http://namespace/" schemaLocation="http://address" />`. Visual Studio handles it properly, Delphi 7 doesn't.

Comment: Then move it from `import` to `include`. I know that some Delphi versions support either import or include, but I forgot which version it was introduced, and I don't have a Delphi 7 handy right now. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the updated importer from here:

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535

Support was added for external schema files.