# xml file as wsdl c# project

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wsdl

Just to let you know this must be a basic question, but I am new to this field.

I am given xml file and asked to import it in C# project as wsdl file.
I know how to import wsdl file in C# project like: Right click on 'Refrences' and then click 'Add Service Refrence' from there we need to select wsdl file.

I am confuse how to convert xml file to wsdl and import it in project.

I really appreciate your help or tips to proceed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A wsdl file *is* an xml file. With wsdl Element as document element. What *exactly* do you have trouble with?

Comment: @LocEngineer
XML code which was given to me doesn't have any xsd tags like '<xsd: elemet'. The code which I have is plain xml. 

I saved it as 'wsdl.wsdl' and tried to import it in C# project as Service Refrence. At this moment it is giving error because it doesn't find any wsdl element.

Comment: Then ask that person who gave you the xml to give you a proper wsdl file. You can't turn crap into whipped cream.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create `WSDL` from `XML` first we have to create `XSD from XML`, Then with created `XSD` we can create a `WSDL`.

**Create XSD from XML:** [Create XSD from XML in Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835730/create-xsd-from-xml-in-code)

**Create WSDL from XSD:** [How to create wsdl from xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669554/how-to-create-wsdl-from-xsd)